# Win RT SQLite Transactional Insert

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime

I'm working on a Win 8 RT app that has to merge some data from a web service to a local SQLite Database, and I've implemented this method to update the database in only transaction.

```
int result;

                await MyDatabaseManager.Connection.RunInTransactionAsync(async (connection) =>
                {
                    foreach (Hotel _hotel in listUpdates)
                    {
                        result = await connection.UpdateAsync(_hotel);

                        if (result == 0)
                        {
                            await MyDatabaseManager.Connection.InsertAsync(_hotel);
                        }
                    }

                });
```

But, I don't know why, when `await connection.UpdateAsync(_hotel);` is invoked, it breaks the for bucle, and exits the function without throw any exception or returns any error.

If I comment the RunInTransactionAsync line, everything works fine.

Any idea??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: would you mind dropping me a line about your experiences with SQLLite, C# and Win RT? We are trying to decide on a database for a Win RT application at the moment. richard at teamhaven dot com.

Answer (score 4):

The [library you're using](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLiteAsync.cs) doesn't have the best `async` support (see [should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) for a description of why the approach is flawed).

You'll need to use the `RunInTransactionAsync(Action<SQLiteConnection>)` overload instead of `RunInTransactionAsync (Action<SQLiteAsyncConnection>)`. This should do it (after you upgrade to the latest version of sqlite-net):

```
await MyDatabaseManager.Connection.RunInTransactionAsync((SQLiteConnection connection) =>
{
  foreach (Hotel _hotel in listUpdates)
  {
    result = connection.Update(_hotel);

    if (result == 0)
    {
      connection.Insert(_hotel);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I have latest sqlite-net version downloaded from NUGet Packacges but It doesn't support your method. It tolds me that I need an SQLiteAsyncConnection to perform the action.

Comment: I wrote my answer based on the sqlite-net source code. I have no association with the project - you're better off contacting them for help.